# Should the tags 'tools' and 'game-accessories' be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I think they should (or one should be eliminated), but I don't have enough rep yet to make that happen.

- [tools](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)
- [game-accessories](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-accessories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. Tools seems vague; I prefer [game-accessories](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-accessories) as the master tag. I'll leave this up for a day or so, then implement the synonym if there are no objections.